# Animate close toggle slide panel?

Tags: jquery, css, animation

I have a simple toggle to open up a slide panel on my site. I used CSS to animate the slide and all works nicely, but how can I add animation to the panel when someone closes the panel? So slide in and out with animation.

**jQuery**

```
$(".toggle-slide-panel").click(function(){
  $(".slide-panel").toggle();
});
```

**CSS**

```
.slide-panel{
background-color: #cccccc;
width: 350px;
height: 100%;
position: fixed;
z-index: 9;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display: none;
animation: slide-panel 300ms;
}

@keyframes slide-panel{
from{
    margin-left: -350px;
    opacity: 0;
}

to{
    margin-left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}
}
```

Comment: JSfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/adwj6bfo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others say as well, i would highly recommend you not to use keyframes as the support is relatively poor (see edit below).

Instead you could just toggle a class with the respective CSS and a transition

```
$(".toggle-slide-panel").click(function(){
$(".slide-panel").toggleClass("active"); 
 });
```

And CSS:

```
.slide-panel{
transform: translate3d(-350px,0,0);
transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.active {
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

You can try it out in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adwj6bfo/2/) which is an update of the one you provided.

**EDIT:** With regard to support I might have been a tad too fast - according to caniuse.com the support for @keyframes and transition is quite similar:
http://caniuse.com/#search=keyframes 
http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

Personally, however, I would still prefer transition over @keyframes, but that might just be because I'm not used to working with keyframes.

**Edit 2:**
If you are concerned about support for older versions, here's just a few notes:

- If you would like to use translate3d (I chose that because it is hardware accelerated; i.e. utilizes the GPU and makes animation smoother) you might want to consider using prefix for the various browsers. Unprefixed and prefixed support can be seen here: http://caniuse.com/#search=translate3d
- If you want almost certain support (for browsers that supports transition, that is) you could just exchange the `translate3d` with a regular `left` property (i.e. `left: -350px;` before toggle and `left: 0;` on the `.active` class). To make this hardware accelerated you could add a `transform: translateZ(0);` to the `.slide-panel` class which also activates it.
- A last alternative is to use a 2d transform `transform: translate(-350px,0)` which has better support than `translate3d` while animating smoother than `left:`.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I had no idea that keyframes where not the right way... Obviously it would need a prefix to work. I just thought that keyframes where better to use rather than loading in jQueryUI.

Comment: @EmmaStone I have made a little edit to my answer as it seems that I might have been a tad too fast. But I wouldn't load jQueryUI for this matter either. You could also just use the jquery `.animate()` instead of loading an extra library

Comment: YES! This is it! Thank you Chris and everyone else. I am used to keyframes rather than transitions, this worked for me :)

Comment: @EmmaStone glad to hear. I have made a little update to the answer yet again, to include some more about support for older browsers

Comment: Great! I will go for transform: translate(-350px,0) as I just want to panel to slide open and close, also this way with CSS I can use media queries to control the panels width and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this link you just might have to add an alternate css for the animation. Something like this
     animation-direction: alternate; /* or: normal */ 
https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/ Hope it helps :).

Comment: Thank you :) I read that one sometime back but it doesn't help with the close animation (

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you not to use CSS keyframes and instead rely on jQuery for the animation.

All you have to do is to add **[jQuery UI](https://code.jquery.com/ui/)** and use the following JS code:

```
$(".toggle-slide-panel").click(function(){
    $(".slide-panel").toggle('slide', {direction: 'left'});
});
```

Take a look at this jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NikolaosG/adwj6bfo/1/ for the specific example.

Comment: Thank you Nikos, that does the trick for sure. But I am using a few JS scripts at the moment, is there an absolute need to use jQueryUI just for this? Appreciate the code sample :)

Comment: I am afraid that jQuery alone cannot really do the trick. jQuery UI allows to easily use **direction** to specify an entire animation that you would otherwise have to use .animate(properties, [values]) in a somewhat weird way to get a similar result.  You can still use the minified version of jQuery UI for minimal impact on performance. :)

Comment: oh I see, I am new to all of this so will look into it :)) thanks again.

Comment: Thanks again Nikos for posting and helping me, Chris below showed me how to do it with css, I will of course save your code for laters. but thank you for the help! :)